# AdapterViewFlipper showing partial/Incomplete TextViews

Tags: android

I'm facing a weird problem. I have a AdapterViewFlipper widget which shows incomplete TextViews. For eg, I've a string of Texts declared as-

```
String fruitNames[] = {"Apple", "Pine Apple", "Litchi", "Mango", "Banana"};
```

Now the problem is, its showing

> "Pine Apple" as "Pine"  and not Pine Apple..the text after space is omitted.

And somtimes, "Litchi" gets displays as "Litc" and Banana as "Bana"

My customadapter is

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
int[] fruitImages;
String[] fruitNames;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] fruitNames, int[] fruitImages) {
this.context = applicationContext;
this.fruitImages = fruitImages;
this.fruitNames = fruitNames;
inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return fruitNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
TextView fruitName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitName);
ImageView fruitImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitImage);
fruitName.setText(fruitNames[position]);
fruitImage.setImageResource(fruitImages[position]);
return view;
}
}
```

In mainacitvity-

```
simpleAdapterViewFlipper = (AdapterViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.simpleAdapterViewFlipper;
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), fruitNames, fruitImages);
simpleAdapterViewFlipper.setAdapter(customAdapter); 
simpleAdapterViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
simpleAdapterViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
}
}
```

I really can't sort out the problem. I tried setting Textview height as match parent of row xml but still it displays partial text..
Kindly help me sort it out pls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/fruitImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/fruitName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thats row layout

Comment: can you share the code of your `R.layout.list_item` layout?

Comment: @SripadRaj added,thanks

Comment: can you try changing TextView's width to `match_parent` and add `android:gravity=center` property?

Comment: I did changed it to match_parent...gravity attribute, i didn't gave a try..but i dont think it matters.

Comment: Please try and let know.

Comment: Never had such weird issue.. What else could be the problem? Earlier I thought it could be text wrapping issue so I changed attribute to match_parent.. Couldn't solve still

Comment: Please try using array adapter with an arraylist of a pojo. I suspect that the views are getting changed when it is getting recycled.

Comment: What happens if you change the width for the `LinearLayout` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`?